# Is there any way to mark a new email from a specific email address with a label using gmail api or through pub sub model in python?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-python-client

Problem: I need to find a way to mark all the emails(past and future) with a specific label that my code just created, I have the label id and I can mark all the past emails but I am unable to find a way to mark the future emails. I am guessing this will require a webhook and I am trying the similar concept currently but I am not getting message id so I don't know how to proceed.

I have tried this code and trying to understand it as to where and how can I make this work in my case where I need my mail to be labelled.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

# TODO(developer)
project_id = "my_project_topic"
subscription_id = "my_subs"
#Number of seconds the subscriber should listen for messages
timeout = 180.0

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
request = {
  'labelIds': ['UNREAD'],
  'labelFilterAction': 'include',
  'topicName': 'projects/my_project_topic/topics/my-subs'
}
service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
# The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_id}`
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    print(f"Received {message}.")
    message.ack()
    #Get message id and use it to get the message from gmail api
    # message_id = message.message_id
    # message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id).execute()
    # print(message['snippet'])


streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber:
    try:
        # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
        # unless an exception is encountered first.
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```

Comment: I would look at creating a filter might be easer https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create

Comment: I used it and I can see my future incoming mails and conversation updates do mark the emails with that label but what about the past sent unread mails already in my inbox?